# Will foresters clear stone and iron?

Tags: banished

If I place a forester hut in an area with lots of stone and iron, will the foresters assigned clear iron and stone in their radius to make room for planting saplings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, ["In the process of planting new trees the foresters will remove loose stone and iron and take these to the nearest stockpile."](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Foresting#Forester_Lodge)

Answer (score 12):

Yes, they will. However I highly recommend marking stone and iron for laborers to clear as it will greatly increase the effectiveness of foresters - if you don't they will spend a lot of time mining and hauling raw material.

Comment: really good tip. That explains why my foresters have been lackluster